# React: unique ID generation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, uuid

Can anyone suggest how I'd go about creating an ID-generating function in React?

So far I've tried to get this to work through an uuid npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid,

```
import uuidv4 from 'uuid'

    helpIdGenerator {
        const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4')
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean in this case? Did you get an error, did you get no output at all, something else?

Comment: Have you tried [`lodash.uniqueid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.uniqueid)?

Comment: After assigning it, `return uuidv4()`

Comment: @HardikModha yeah, but how would I put inside a function?

Answer (score 13):

This function may be useful:

```
function guidGenerator() {
    var S4 = function() {
       return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1);
    };
    return (S4()+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+S4()+S4());
}
```

this generates random ids like this:

> 6b33fce8-1745-f8de-4ad8-4ee42585oprf

Comment: This is great. Thank you sr

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```js
import uuid from 'react-native-uuid'

let id = uuid.v1()
```

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

Fixed by using:

```
helpIdGenerator = () => {

    const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4')

}
```